# In circleCI config which one should be first, save-cache or restore-cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, config, circleci

I am new to circleci. Kindly correct me if my understanding of the concept is wrong.

I was going through the documentation. In the documentation [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#restore_cache), it says

> Restores a previously saved cache based on a key

Does it mean, there should be `save-cache`, before `restore-cache`?

And in few sample config files `restore-cache` is written before `save-cache`. Like [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#full-example-of-saving-and-restoring-cache)

Answer (score 0):

`Previously saved cache` mean the saved cache from previously build.
So you need to write `restore-cache` before `save-cache` to no need to install again if there is no change in dependencies.

For example:

1st Build: dependencies A and B -> install -> save to cache-1

2nd Build: dependencies A and B (no change) -> use cache-1 (no need to install)

3rd Build: dependencies A, B and C -> install -> save to cache-2

Comment: If I am not wrong, If save-cache is written first, it won't create a new cache if there is already a cache with same key.

Comment: thats right, it won't create a new cache in that case, but save-cache is written first then in first build, what will be cached? because that time dependencies have not be installed yet.

Comment: Okay. Then vice-versa, i.e., when restore-cache is written first, what will be restored?

Comment: vice-versa, in 1st build because there is no cache so nothing is restore but from 2nd build previous build's saved cache is restored